# Accented characters not rendering correctly on title bar in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, 14.04, window

So I've noticed this problem after I upgraded from Ubuntu 13.10 a few days back. I've noticed that whenever a window title is supposed to contain any accented character like "ï", the title bar replaces the character with a box

[image: Here's a screenshot]

Notice that "Daïa" is displaying correctly inside the window but not on the title bar. Also, this problem only appears when the window in question is not maximised. Upon maximising the window, the character renders correctly.

My question is, why is this happening and how can I fix this? Is this a bug? I'd appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest reporting this as a bug on Launchpad. I'm not sure against what package, though.

Comment: Not only the accented characters but the many special characters are not appearing on window title bar. Try searching something and you'll see the "" are not rendering correctly. The characters appear correctly in the ubuntu panel in the maximized mode.

Comment: @UttamPal
Maybe this could apply
http://askubuntu.com/questions/796979/unity-16-04-accented-letters-dont-show-in-dash-hud-and-are-replaced-in-window/821882#821882