# Weird "Box-like" Characters Showing up in Title Bar of Windows

Tags: 14.04, unity, window, titlebar

[Screenshots]

[image]

[image]

Why do these box-like characters appear? They disappear once the window is maximised.
I can see something similar here: [Accented characters not rendering correctly on title bar in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498153/accented-characters-not-rendering-correctly-on-title-bar-in-ubuntu-14-04)

What is the problem? How can I get rid of them?

Comment: My fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04.01 LTS did the same thing but with characters that I typed into the Unity searchbar until I fully updated via Software Updater and also got the latest, tested, proprietary graphics drivers. Let me know what's up and if this helps. Also, can you recreate this problem every time exactly? Or is it random?

Comment: I have also faced the same - http://pasteboard.co/2dE6b9yI.png

Comment: @MikeUresti Maybe this could apply
http://askubuntu.com/questions/796979/unity-16-04-accented-letters-dont-show-in-dash-hud-and-are-replaced-in-window/821882#821882