# Certain characters not rendering on Ubuntu title bar and Mozilla gmail and some other sites

Tags: 14.04, firefox, fonts, titlebar

I've noticed a weird problem on a new install Ubuntu 14.04 on a new build machine.  It may be the same problem as this:
[Accented characters not rendering correctly on title bar in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498153/accented-characters-not-rendering-correctly-on-title-bar-in-ubuntu-14-04)
and
[Weird "Box-like" Characters Showing up in Title Bar of Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/533059/weird-box-like-characters-showing-up-in-title-bar-of-windows)

As I type this the title bar reads: "Certai? characters ?ot re?deri?g o? Ubu?tu bar a?d some other sites - Ask Ubu?tu - Chromium"

I then maximised the title bar and it suddenly reads no problem.

So the problem is intermittent, and the specific letter with which it is struggling changes.

I've noticed the same problem in Mozilla Firefox.  Initially gmail was almost unreadable there were so many letters replaced by random squiggles.  Then I found a workaround of increasing the zoom.  Now I've opened it up with 100% zoom and everything is okay.  I then reduce it to 90% zoom and a bunch of characters turn into squiggles:

100% zoom on gmail home page on Mozilla:
[image: Mozilla gmail screen 100 percent zoom]

90% zoom on gmail home page on Mozilla:
[image: Mozilla gmail screen 90 percent zoom]

Here's another screen shot of an Ubuntu Software Updater message box:
[image: Ubuntu Software Updater Message Box]

Anyway, my fonts are all shared appropriately, and I've never seen the issue in gmail in Chromium.

Any ideas?

(My hardware is detailed here: http://drxorile.tumblr.com/post/114188429334/computer-build)

Comment: Just a side note, as I can't help you with your problem (sorry). If I'm not mistaken you can upload images, but you cannot embed them as images, just keep them as links. Those Google images don't work for everybody, they give a forbidden error (403).

Comment: Thanks, Dan.  I've fixed the links (hopefully).  Uploading would probably have been better...

Comment: Is your Ubuntu OS English or a localized version?

Comment: My Ubuntu is English

Comment: I noticed the same problem today.  It seems to have started a few hours ago?  Also shows up in menu text values (in Firefox and Chromium).  I rebooted the system and the problem seems to have disappeared??

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had an answer.  I don't have enough of a reputation to leave a comment, so I will ask my question here.  What hardware are you running on?  What display driver are you using?  I have similar problems on a t450s which uses the Intel Broadwell HD Graphics 5500.  Example screen shots.

Notice the missing u in Buffers and the missing s in Lisp from the emacs menu bar in [emacs menubar screenshot](http://i724.photobucket.com/albums/ww247/seth43/Screenshot%20from%202015-03-20%20170902_zpsecqh1qny.png).  What I can't show you is that if I click on the menu item it will show all the letters, because, I think it is in a different font.

Notice the garbled entries in my thunderbird list of email subjects in the [thunderbird screen shot](http://i724.photobucket.com/albums/ww247/seth43/Screenshot%20from%202015-03-20%20171216_zpsxmonclmn.png).  Also the missing folder names.  This is not a thunderbird issue, but a rendering issue.  I can click on them and they open up.

Is this anything like what you are experiencing?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience.  I would guess that this is slightly different.  It looks to me like your font is rendering correctly, but too big.  In some cases not rendering an all.  But it may be a slightly similar issue.

Comment: My hardware is detailed here: http://drxorile.tumblr.com/post/114188429334/computer-build